# Files Context Menu too limited

Tags: file-browser

Is there a way to incorporate Windows file context menu into the blender context menu?

For example, when I use 3dsMax, I am able to right-click on a file use use something like OpenWith to launch my installation of GIMP to graphically edit and refine an image.  Whereas with blender I need to copy the location, and then open up file manager, search for the file (perhaps a folder with many files), and then OpenWith.

when using a more File-Explorer-like interface, I can also highlight/find the file in a large folder by replacing the last letter the '*' end hit enter to narrow/filter the file list.  Again a great convenience that I don't have with blender File View.

Am I over-looking a way to regain this productivity in blender?

Comment: where's is the suggestions, feedback. For blender the devtalk.blender.org is confusing and immature, for a product that's been around for years. sad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the blender file browser is limited, but there are some workarounds for both of the things you mentioned.

1. Editing images. Blender has an option in the image editor to “edit externally,“ which can be set in user preferences to open images in whatever your favorite image editor program is (GIMP in my case), and then you can reload the image from the source to update it when you’re done.
2. Filtering. The file browser itself has search box in the header at the top that does not look in subdirectories. Try this for quick filtering of large directories.

Comment: Okay, bravo for the filtering, but I think external editor (already had it set to GIMP) gives no love withing the file browser:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qsi9qzuzcyxan65/externalGraphicsEditor.png?dl=0 ... is only for images I render.  I want to jump into GIMP to edit an Image Texture node in Shader.

Comment: Interestingly enough (off-topic) Edit (rendered) Image Externally is throwing an error: "image path '.' is not found", even though I have a full output path set up in Output Properties!  groan!

Comment: "file browser is limited":  where's is the suggestions, feedback.  For blender the https://devtalk.blender.org/ is confusing and immature, for a product that's been around for years.  sad.

Comment: No, the file browser does not allow you to live and external image. That might be useful in some cases. You cannot edit an image from the texture node, but you can select that same image in the blender image editor, then use the “edit externally“ option. It’s the same image data block.